# Installing "Heroes of the Storm"

Tags: wine, games

I went to the BlizzCon .. great time and I saw their new game Hero Of The Storm - http://www.heroesofthestorm.com/en-us

But I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and when I try to install it, it does not work, nothing happens ... no launcher... no screens ... nothing.

I already have Diablo 3 and WOW installed ... So yes I have Wine installed.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**
My old answer seems invalid now. There are testimonies on [winehq.org](https://appdb.winehq.org) that ["Heroes of the Storm"](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=31553) is working. I don't own the game and can't verify anything.

Anyone with a step-by-step instruction for Ubuntu: Feel free to post your own answer or improve this one.

Comment: let's hope ... for an update soon from winehq

Comment: Well, instead just waiting, you could also add an entry yourself and gather all the information you can and add a app-entry to the [winehq page](http://winehq.org/). This isn't all that easy, but still do-able. You would be building the foundation of some more information gathering (systems outside of Ubuntu) and could draw-in more people with wine-tweaking and wine-developing skills. I'm sure there is some [guide](https://appdb.winehq.org/help/?sTopic=appdb_faq) out there how to get started.

Comment: I wish ... I am no genius ...

Comment: People are giving it a platinum rating now for Ubuntu, however when I install it, it crashes immediately when the installer starts

Comment: Installation and game work fine now, but performance is bad for me only ~20 fps. Figuring out how to get more atm.

Comment: I've update my answer to reflect the current state. Feel free to improve it or to add your own answer.